Does the 'Del' operator follow matrix multiplication rules
Summary:
I am having trouble understanding if the del operator ($\nabla$) follows the rules for matrix multiplication. If not, can someone recommend a good textbook explaining the rules for using the del operator on vectors, matrices, and tensors in general?

More details:
I know that the rule for matrix multiplication is
$$ (AB)_{ij} = C_{ij} = \sum_k a_{ik}b_{kj}$$
so you get something like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} \\
b_{21} \\
b_{31} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} + a_{13}b_{31} \\
a_{21}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{21} + a_{23}b_{31} \\
a_{31}b_{11} + a_{32}b_{21} + a_{33}b_{31} \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Does the "vector-like" del operator follow the same rules?
Would that make the outer product of del and a vector
$$ 
\nabla \mathbf{a}^T
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_x \\
\partial_y \\
\partial_z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_x & a_y & a_z \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_x a_x & \partial_x a_y & \partial_x a_z \\
\partial_y a_x & \partial_y a_y & \partial_y a_z \\
\partial_z a_x & \partial_z a_y & \partial_z a_z \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
?
I have seen this given as the definition of the gradient of a vector, but also the Jacobian matrix as another definition where the indices are interchanged.
If you were to multiply this matrix by a vector and for it to have clear meaning, would you not have to take the transpose of the matrix so you would have something like
$$
(\nabla \mathbf{a}^T)^T \mathbf{ds} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_x a_x & \partial_y a_x & \partial_z a_x \\
\partial_x a_y & \partial_y a_y & \partial_z a_y \\
\partial_x a_z & \partial_y a_z & \partial_z a_z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
dx \\
dy \\
dz \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
(\partial_x a_x)dx + (\partial_y a_x)dy + (\partial_z a_x)dz \\
(\partial_x a_y)dx + (\partial_y a_y)dy + (\partial_z a_y)dz \\
(\partial_x a_z)dx + (\partial_y a_z)dy + (\partial_z a_z)dz \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I know that the dot product of two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ is
$$ \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{b}$$
but is this true for the dot product of a matrix and a vector, if that is even what you would call it when it isn't two vectors? Inner product?
I am just a bit confused about the notation, rules and consequences of treating $\nabla$ like a vector at least some of the time.
Any explanations or recommendations for further reading would be appreciated.
Thanks!

From WP: "As a vector operator, del naturally acts on scalar fields via scalar multiplication, and naturally acts on vector fields via dot products and cross products." The Jacobian is indeed the awful expression $(\nabla a^\top)^\top$ but no one forces you to use that.

I think that maybe what you're trying to say is that you are confused about the use of the notation $\nabla a$ for the "gradient" of a vector $a$, since if $\nabla$ is treated as a vector then $\nabla a^T$ since makes more sense. Is that right? (The secret, by the way, is that a lot of the time what people mean by $\nabla a$ is actually a tensor product $\nabla\otimes a$.)

@NicholasTodoroff Thanks for your reply, Nicholas. Is the tensor product the outer product? Wikipedia says "The outer product of tensors is also referred to as their tensor product, and can be used to define the tensor algebra." But wasn't sure if that was the case for tensors in genral or just vectors.

The outer product of two column vectors gives the components of the tensor product of two vectors in the standard basis, but the tensor product is a more general/abstract thing. In particular you can have tensor products of arbitrarily many vectors $v_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_n$ but there is no natural way to use matrices except when $n = 2$.

There is also a difference between $\nabla\otimes a$ and $\nabla a^T$ in that the first is a $(0,2)$-tensor and the second is a $(1,1)$-tensor, though the fact that we're working in $\mathbb R^m$ obscures this since in this case these two objects can be naturally identified.
